# touchpad not lock after suspend

Tags: 16.04, mouse, suspend, touchpad

I usually use mouse, I do not use touchpad. On my computer, I press `fn+f8` to disable the touchpad. However, every time after resume from suspend, the touchpad is active again, which is quite annoying when typing.

I just wonder why it is active again when resume from suspend, I just want to disable it once, and when I really need it, I can press `fn+f8` to active it.

Comment: Instead of using the key combo, may I interest you in a shortcut? Using `xinput`, identify the ID of your touchpad, and then bind keys or create a desktop shortcut that runs the command `xinput disable <id>`, and a shortcut that runs the command `xinput enable <id>`. You can even have it disable at boot.

Comment: @PatrickNegus thanks for the comment. Things is not very bad, I can disable it after the suspend by press `fn+f8` again. The problem is that I sometimes forget to do so after resume. Besides, I can disable the touch pad in the settings easily.